# configure: error: failed to find required module libxml2, while building mesa

Tags: software-installation

When executing `./configure` command for Mesa-9.1.3 I get the following error:

```
checking python2 module: libxml2... no  
configure: error: failed to find required module libxml2
```

when I already have `libxml2` installed, and on executing `apt-get install libxml2`:

```
libxml2 is already the newest version.
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because you lack the proper headers libraries for mesa. One way to solve them all is installing all the libraries with a single stroke:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep mesa
```

For the specific message you may need:

```
sudo apt-get install python-libxml2
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this was kind of tricky, and saying that libxml2 is missing is a bad error. What is really missing (at least in my case was) python-libxml2

Comment: Didn't work for me :( I have "libxml2" and "libxml2-devel", and there's no python-libxml2 for my package manager (yum/fedora).